# Adding B2Bodies to sprite Node causes sprite location to change

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a batchnode of sprites that are getting added to the scene. The locations of these sprites are off set from the position of the batchnde so I can rotate them about the point of the batch node.

The problem occurs when I attach a B2Body to any of these sprites, their position on the screen changes.

```
    balloon1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"1.png"];
    balloon1.position = ccp(30,30);
    balloon1.tag = 10;
    //balloon1.anchorPoint = ccp(1.1,0.7);
    [spriteNode addChild:balloon1];

    b2BodyDef balloonBodyDef;
balloonBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
balloonBodyDef.position.Set((160 + balloon1.position.y)/PTM_RATIO, (240 -          balloon1.position.x)/PTM_RATIO);
balloonBodyDef.userData = balloon1;
b2Body *balloonBody = world->CreateBody(&balloonBodyDef);

b2PolygonShape balloon;
    balloon.SetAsBox((balloon1.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2),
               (balloon1.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2));


// Create shape definition and add to body
b2FixtureDef laserGunShapeDef;
laserGunShapeDef.shape = &laser;
//laserGunShapeDef.density = 0.0f;
//laserGunShapeDef.friction = 10.0f;
//laserGunShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;

b2Fixture *balloonFixture = balloonBody->CreateFixture(&laserGunShapeDef);
```

If I add the balloon as a sprite from a file, this works ok, but when its done as above, then the balloon moves off the screen.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
balloonBodyDef.position.Set((160 + balloon1.position.y)/PTM_RATIO, (240 -          balloon1.position.x)/PTM_RATIO);
```

To

```
balloonBodyDef.position.Set(balloon1.position.x/PTM_RATIO, balloon1.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
```

Also handle position updates in tick method.

```
balloon1.position = ccp(balloonBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                            (balloonBody->GetPosition().y) * PTM_RATIO);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I am still having the same problem. The code works if a add a sprite to the scene, but if I add a sprite from a batchnode, then the sprite seems to be offset.

Comment: try spriteNode.position=ccp(0.0f,0.0f);

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing, but it is probably because of the spriteNode position. Since the sprite is attached to the sprite node, (30, 30) is relative to the position of the sprite node, not the actual world's coordinate.

So, try using

```
CGPoint worldCoordinate = [spriteNode convertToWorldSpace: balloon1.position];
balloonBodyDef.position.Set(worldCoordinate.x/PTM_RATIO, worldCoordinate.y/PTM_RATIO);
```

and like Guru said, don't forget to update the position of your sprite on the tick method. If this doesn't work, its a wild guess and it shouldn't matter... but try setting the position of the body first, and then set the position of the balloon from that body.

anyways hope this helps.